# Replace gazebo canopy with hard top

Tags: roof, outdoor, shed

I have a a steel frame gazebo with ripped canopy. Therefore, I was thinking of replacing the canopy with hard top. I have started my research and I arrived at these options
1- Ondura corrugated panel (Asphalt/fiberglass) which is around $22 a panel
2- Suntuf corrugated panel (polycarbonate) which is around $55 a panel.

Obviously  I would opt in for the cheaper option but is there a strong reason I should go (or should not go) with one or the other? Or perhaps another panel I am not aware of.

Can these panels be installed on the steel beams directly (  beams are like this)

[image]

The gazebo frame I have is 10 by 12

I greatly appreciate your advice

Thank you